# Having an 'Undefined Method' error in my Ruby on Rails Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently in the middle of a project where we have to use Ruby on Rails which I haven't used before. I am trying to add a login system and found a guide using AuthLogic (https://gist.github.com/ahmadhasankhan/858801cda04a56ee0c17) and everything was working as I expected until the 12th step. I try to add:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
c.login_field = :email
end
```

to my user.rb file.

However, when I try to update the page I get 'undefined method `acts_as_authentic' for main:Object'.

Being a complete newby and unable to find any help to fix this specific issue thought I'd ask.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you run the `bundle` command to install the third party code that `acts_as_authentic` probably comes from?

Comment: I have yes, I ran it again there to double check but still have the same error. I followed the guide exactly as it is which is why I'm having difficulty finding the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the code goes inside the User class, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.login_field = :email
  end
end
```

Comment: Well I thought I had tried that but mustn't have saved it properly haha, such an obvious mistake too. Thank you so much, really appreciate it!